# How to perform hyperparameter tuning of susi-som clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis

how to perform hyperparameter tuning of susi som clustering?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
# Create the SOM model
param_grid = {
    
    "n_iter_unsupervised": randint(1000, 3000),
    "distance_metric":  ["euclidean", "manhattan", "mahalanobis","tanimoto", "spectralangle"],
    "learning_rate_start": uniform(0.1, 5),
    "learning_rate_end": uniform(0.1, 5),
    "nbh_dist_weight_mode":["pseudo-gaussian", "mexican-hat"],
    "random_state":randint(1, 150),
}
som_wrapper = susi.SOMClustering(n_rows=3,n_columns=1)

clust = RandomizedSearchCV(som_wrapper, param_grid,
                          n_iter=10,         # Number of random combinations to try
                          cv=5,              # Number of cross-validation folds
                          random_state=42,   # Set random state for reproducibility
                          n_jobs=-1,scoring = "adjusted_mutual_info_score" )

clust.fit(x)
print("SOM fitted!")
```

print(clust.best_params_)

TypeError: Cannot clone object '<susi.SOMClustering.SOMClustering object at 0x78a95977cdf0>' (type <class 'susi.SOMClustering.SOMClustering'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' method.